# What is the required signal-to-noise ratio for a AX5042 transceiver?

Tags: electronics

What is the required signal-to-noise ratio of a AX5042 transceiver IC?

Answer (score 1):

A manufacturer will specify the receiver sensitivity at a particular bit transmission rate and not the minimum signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) required for the receiver to demodulate.This is because the receive sensitivity is the most important specification needed when designing wireless systems, not the minimum SNR.So when you are performing a link budget, you have to make sure that the power that reaches your receiver is at least equal to the receive sensitivity if you want to maintain a good BER.

The receive sensitivity is the minimum signal power that should reach the receiver for there to be "successful demodulation".Successful demodulation is usually defined as there being a BER of at least $10^{-9}$ but a manufacturer can chose to specify a receive sensitivity relating to another BER value (if this is done then that BER is explicitly stated).